# How do I search for the source code of this function that is from an open source library?

Tags: open-source

I am trying to understand what this function does in line 178 of https://github.com/PhilippJKratzer/humoro/blob/master/humoro/player_pybullet.py

```
p.resetJointStatesMultiDof(self._humans[human], idxes, values)
```

where `p` is an alias for `pybullet` https://pypi.org/project/pybullet/. However, I am unable to find the source code of `resetJointStatesMultiDof` even after going through the github webpage at https://github.com/bulletphysics/bullet3. Could someone kindly assist?